# Find using NOT Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have VBA that searches for a font that is colored red, and takes action.

VBA 2007 does not like this syntax:

```
With myRg.Find
      .Font.ColorIndex <> wdBlack
```

Can I search for NON-black or any `not` criteria?

Comment: The equal sign there is not a comparison, it's an assignment.

Comment: I have a document over 100 pages and it would be nice if I could look for comments that people put in with color font (e.g. blue, but may vary), and also skip web references (which are often in color)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you wish to do cannot be done, but this work-around may be of interest: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.beginners/2005-12/msg00012.html